# Set representation of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S=\Big\{f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}: \exists \;\epsilon>0 \;\text{ such that}\;\forall \delta \>>0, \vert x-y \vert<\delta \Rightarrow\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert <\epsilon \big\}$. Then
>
> a)  $S=\Big\{f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}: f\; \text{is continuous} \}$
>
> b) $S=\Big\{f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}: f\; \text{is uniformly continuous} \}$
>
> c) $S=\Big\{f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}: f\; \text{is bounded} \}$
>
> d) $S=\Big\{f: \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}: f\; \text{is constant} \}$

I know a) and b) are not true. Also every constant function satisfies this, so d) is true. But the answer is c). How to prove c)?

Any hint?

Comment: Take any real value $x$, for your value of $\epsilon$, $|f(y)|<|f(x)|+\epsilon$ for every $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be in $S$. That means there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $\delta$, whenever, $|x-y|<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. So, choose $y-0$. Then for any $|x|<\delta$, $f(x)\in[f(0)-\epsilon,f(0)+\epsilon]$. But this is true for all $\delta$. So we have no restriction on $x$. Thus, for any $x$, $f(x)$ is between $f(0)-\epsilon$ and $f(0)+\epsilon$. Thus $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Option $(d)$ cannot be true. For example consider the function $\sin x$ then $\sin \in S$ since $\exists \,\varepsilon = 5$ such that $\mid\sin x -\sin y \mid< 5$ for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}.$ But $\sin$ is not a constant function.

However $(c)$ is true.

As mentioned in the comments, for a fixed $y$ and $\varepsilon$, we have $\mid f(x)-f(y)\mid<\varepsilon, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$

Since $\mid |f(x)|-|f(y)|\mid <\mid f(x)-f(y)\mid<\varepsilon,$

we have, $|f(x)|<|f(y)|+\varepsilon, \forall x\in \mathbb{R}.$

this implies $f(x)$ is bounded.